# SPFieldMultiChoice - can there be an underlying value?

Tags: sharepoint

With Sharepoint's SPFieldMultiChoice, there is a [stringcollection] "Choices" property and a [string] "Mappings" property.  These can come from a [schema.xml file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms459356.aspx).  I have not seen where the out of the box functionality provides for usage of the values stored in .  In other words, rendering a ListControl with Display text and underlying values.  Easy enough to create, but just checking to see what i'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the SPFieldMultiChoiceValue class. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldmultichoicevalue(v=office.12).aspx

Here is a simple tutorial explaining how to use this for example with a checkbox list.

http://blog.qumsieh.ca/2008/12/27/working-with-spfieldmultichoicevalue-saving-and-loading/

***edit  After rereading your question I realized the context was wrong. No a multichoice field is not a key/value pair it is simply a valued index.

Comment: Right, i'm looking for a way to *Present* user-friendly values while storing/persisting the *real* values.  Example: "English" is diplayed to the user while "en" is the actual value.  For now, i'm just whipping up my own SPFieldMultiChoice-derived class and overriding the FieldRenderingControl.